# Operator with 3 variables highest variable show name with pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, max, operators

I'm trying to obtain the variable with the highest number so basically this are the variables:

```
number_no = 17
number_yes = 2
number_dontknow = 10
```

I would like to know with one is the highest I was using max(number_no, number_yes) but it gave me the number and I need the variable name, so I would like to have something like:

```
highest_variable = max(number_no, number_yes)

if highest_variable == number_no:
   total = sum(number_no + number_yes + number_dontknow)
   percentage = number_no/total
   print(percentage+ "%")
   #Show percentage to use it in another function
if else highest_variable == number_yes:
   total = sum(number_no + number_yes + number_dontknow)
   percentage = number_yes/total
   print(percentage+ "%")
   #Show percentage to use it in another function
```

Comment: How about sort and take the first number out. Add the variables in a list, and sort the list and take the 0th element out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the highest name and highest value:

```
number_no = 17
number_yes = 2
number_dontknow = 10 

numbers_name = ["number_no","number_yes","number_dontknow"]
numbers_value = [number_no,number_yes,number_dontknow]
highest_value = max(number_no,number_yes,number_dontknow)
highest_name = numbers_name[numbers_value.index(highest_value)]

print(highest_name,highest_value)

# output: ('number_no', 17)
```

Comment: and how can I normalize the highest_value?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: percentage = highest_value / sum(numbers_value)

Comment: Yes exaclty like that
 percentage = highest_value / sum(numbers_value)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly?

But if I understand correctly:

- The 1st solution is that use `max` rather the variable:

```py
total = sum(number_no + number_yes + number_dontknow)
percentage = max(number_no, number_yes)/total
print(percentage+ "%")
#Show percentage to use it in another function
```

- The 2nd solution is that swap sort numbers to sure that one if highest. In this code We could be sure that number_yes is highest:

```py
if number_no > number_yes:
  number_yes , number_no = number_no , number_yes

total = sum(number_no + number_yes + number_dontknow)
percentage = number_yes/total
print(percentage+ "%")
#Show percentage to use it in another function
```

- I don't understand why you use `sum()`?
  **I think you mean:**

```py
total = number_no + number_yes + number_dontknow
```